# What's a good translation for "awkward" in the context of "awkward person" or "awkward situation"?

Tags: translation, single-word-request

There doesn't really seem to be a German word with the exact same meanings and connotations as the English word "awkward". How would you translate it in a sentence like "He's an awkward person" or "That was an awkward situation."?

Comment: What is the exact meaning, and what are the connotations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A situation can be *unangenehm* or *prekär*. Similarly a person can be *unangenehm*. Or *schwierig*, *seltsam* or *unbeholfen*.

I agree that there doesn't seem to be a word that captures the connotation of *awkward* 1:1. It depends on the situation.

That being said without knowing more about the context I'd translate the first sentence as

> Er ist eine seltsame Person.

It sounds a bit weird though. Using *schon* makes the sentence a bit more elegant but being a native speaker unfortunately I can't give you a rationale for that.

> Er ist schon eine seltsame Person/Persönlichkeit.

The second sentence could be

> Das war eine unangenehme Situation.

Comment: imo *seltsam* fits best, as it has the same unclear meaning and contextual character as *awkward*. *awkward* itself is a very weird term, not only because of spelling...

Answer (score 4):

Regarding a situation:

- heikel
- unbehaglich
- peinlich

depending on the context. For general usage, I think *heikel* fits best here together with *unangenehm* as suggested by [musiKk](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/whats-a-good-translation-for-awkward-in-the-context-of-awkward-person-or-aw/2302#2302).

As for a person, "linkisch" seems to fit as well.

Comment: I really like "linkisch" as a translation.

Comment: I don't really care too much for *linkisch*. Maybe it's because I'm a lefty. ;)

Comment: @Cassandrexx: I find _linkisch_ very strong and somewhat offending. In comparison, _unbeholfen_ is a lot nicer. But of course it depends on the situation which connotation you want.

Comment: @Hendrik: I'd say "awkward" is pretty strong and somewhat hurtful when applied to a person, too. But of course you're right, it depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

What about *merkwürdig* in the sense of "somehow strange"?

The phrase

> Er ist eine merkwürdige Person.

seems to fit, as well as

> Das war eine merkwürdige Situation.

And for me, *merkwürdig* has - phonetically and also regarding usage - the exact same connotation as *awkward*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in an awkward situation your feelings might be defined as *Verlegenheit*, e.g.:

> Du hast mich in Verlegenheit gebracht.

Comment: Man *bringt* jemanden in Verlegenheit.

Comment: I see. You have put me in an awkward situation...is that right?

Comment: The OP asked how you would translate "awkward situation" and I'm asking if "Verlegenheit" is a good match.

Comment: Yes, *awkward situation* can be translated as being in an *unangenehme* or a *peinliche Situation* or simply being *verlegen*. What I just said is that in German you are *brought* into an awkward situation rather than *put*: "Du hast mich in Verlegenheit gebracht" - "jemanden in Verlegenheit bringen". This word, however, would not fit in context of *awkward person*. *Schwierig* (difficult) or *unangenehm* could be the right choice. When OP said there isn't really a German word, I disagree because *unangenehm* fits in most contexts. Well, this comment hast the quality of being an answer, now.

Comment: Well, since you mention a "peinliche situation", I have to confess that although I am not a native speaker (or even reasonably fluent) I have had some extensive discussions on the nuances of these things, and I have the impression that a Peinlichkeit is more of an embarrassing situation than an awkward situation. Do you think German speakers would distinguish a Peinlichkeit from a Verlegenheit as I have suggested?

Comment: *peinlich* and *verlegen* are quite related in sense. Same in English. Duden defines *peinlich* as *ein Gefühl der Verlegenheit, des Unbehagens, der Beschämung*, and *verlegen* as *in einer peinlichen, unangenehmen Situation nicht so recht wissend, wie man sich verhalten soll*. I consider *peinlich* stronger than *verlegen*. And most times you put yourself into a *peinliche Situation* whereas other people will make you *verlegen*.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it more suitable. If you don't agree, revise it again. Otherwise let's clean up our comments, please. If you have any further questions about this, ask a new question or enter the chat room, please.

Comment: When you say "let's clean up our comments please" I understand that you find something inappropriate in my comments. I do not feel I have said anything that needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: It has simply been a long discussion whereas I was only about explaining why your original post was not fully correct (in sense of idiomatic German). And the discussion about differences between *Peinlichkeit* and *Verlegenheit* are not helpful to anyone in future since these are comments and not a question that is easy to find via search. Sometimes it's better to remove long discussions when the reason for the discussion has been clarified.

Answer (score 2):

#### [Komisch:](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/komisch)

Somewhat of a false friend with English.  It means 'funny' but in the sense that funny can mean weird.

> "Schau mal diesen komischen Typ an!"