# Welches deutsche Wort entspricht am besten dem Englischen „awkward“?

Tags: translation

Ist das passende Wort peinlich oder unangenehm? Ich hab Beides gehört.

Comment: Without context this can't be answered with confidence. The English word is not really better in that respect, but at least an example would be helpful. For a context-free search ask the dictionary of your choice.

Comment: You should get used to the idea that languages are not about single word meanings. Languages are about complex forms of expressing complex ideas. Therefore, speaking about meaning without context is... meaningless.

Comment: Bissige Kommentare sind keinem behilflich und sind unerwünscht. „You should get used to the idea“ hört sich auf Englisch gemein an und ist höchst unhöflich. Und warum schreibt man auf Englisch, wenn alles auf Deutsch geschrieben werden soll? Es gibt ein englisch.stackexchage.com Forum, und ich interessiere mich gar nicht für die englische Sprache und will es in diesem Forum nicht lesen. Danke.

Comment: Wenn man eine Frage auf Deutsch stellt, und ein anderer die Frage auf Englisch antwortet, ist das klip und klar eine Beleidigung,

Comment: @SteveL Diese Community hat schon mehrfach darüber diskutiert und ist zu dem [Schluss](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/ist-es-in-ordnung-englische-fragen-auf-deutsch-zu-beantworten/1387#1387) gekommen, dass es zwar wünschenswert ist, Fragen in der selben Sprache zu beantworten, es aber keine Regel ist, die durchgesetzt werden MUSS. Fühl Dich also bitte nicht beleidigt.

Comment: Related question: [What's a good translation for "awkward" in the context of "awkward person" or "awkward situation"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2300/19201)

Comment: Mir ist egal worüber die Community diskutiert hat, und zu weichem Schluß sie gekommen ist. Wenn man eine Frage auf Deutsch stellt, und ausdrücklich darum bittet,  daß keiner die Frage auf Englisch beantwortet, werde ich solche Antworten in englischer Sprache nicht lesen. Warum beantwortet man die Fragen nicht auf andere Sprachen? Einige Kommentare auf English lauten: „For a context-free search ask the dictionary of your choice.“ Hä? Wie kann man ein Buch etwas fragen? Ein Buch is kein Mensch. Er muß „consult“ oder „look up in“ gemeint haben.

Answer (score 12):

It's all about context.

> an awkward situation
>   – ein peinlicher Moment *(embarrassing)*
>   – eine unangenehme Situation, eine missliche Lage *(difficult)*
>
> an awkward attempt – ein ungeschickter, unbeholfener Versuch *(due to lack of skill or expertise)*
>
> move awkwardly – sich ungelenk, unbeholfen bewegen  *(due to bodily impairment)*
>
> an awkward teenager – ein unsicherer, unbeholfener Teenager *(lacking social grace)*
>
> smile awkwardly — verlegen lächeln *(characterised by shyness)*
>
> an awkward silence – verlegenes Schweigen *(embarrassed and not knowing what to do)*
>
> an awkward angle – ein ungeschickter*, ungünstiger, unpraktischer Winkel *(hard to deal with)*

<sub>* [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ungeschickt#Bedeutung2a]) says this meaning of *ungeschickt* is mainly common in the South of Germany.</sub>

The historically primary meaning of *awk* + *ward* seems to be *in the wrong direction, backwards*. The curious *awk* "turned the wrong way" seems to be related to German *äbich* "verkehrt herum", which is an old word that nevertheless seems to have persisted in certain dialects.<sup>[1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/awk) [2](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?lemma=aebich)</sup>

<sub>Nur, weil es amüsant ist: Lessing schlägt als Synonym für *äbicht* *ärschlings* vor: [hier](https://visuallibrary.net/ihd/content/pageview/105667) und die [Folgeseite](https://visuallibrary.net/ihd/content/pageview/105668). Vielleicht sollte man wieder einführen: *Geh, oder ich will dir mit der äbichten eins geben.*</sub>

Comment: Mir ist das Wort „heikel“ zuerst aufgefallen. Eine heikle Sache, heikleres Thema, eine heikle Frage. Die Sache ist äußerst heikel. Ihre Lage wird immer heikler. Meines Erachens, hat „awkward“ nichts mit Verlegenheit,  Ungeschicklichkeit oder Peinlichkeit zu tun. Aber, trotzdem vielen Dank für die Anworten.

Comment: *Heikel* goes in the direction of *difficult, tricky, delicate* and would fit in many cases. But it does not fit in all of the instances mentioned above. To give further examples: an *awkward throw* is not *heikel*, it's *ungeschickt*; an *awkward silence* is not *heikel*, it's *verlegenes Schweigen*

Comment: Überlegte grad, ob *heikel* wenigstens etymologisch passt, aber es Ist leider "ungeklärt". Bei awk sieht man Swedisch "avig", und ich denke mir "affig", alles geklärt. Ernsthafte Vergleiche legen weiterhin einen Germanischen Stamm "ab-" nahe, daher wäre "absurd" einiger maßen passend. Dort steht PIE \*swer-, siehe dazu auch *schwer*. Das kann man *unschwer* erkennen. Nimmt man also eine Negativebildung an, wäre "**abwegig**" wohl nicht all zu abwegig. Dass "schwer zu ertragen", "schwer pubertierend", *schwerfällig*, etc. in vielerlei hinsicht passt, könnte zufall sein.

Comment: "äbicht" oder "ärschlings" (zweiteres kenne ich, ersteres scheint mir sehr selten) ist ähnlich - auch in der Bedeutung - zu *überzwerch*, was im Übrigen (auch) eine passende Überwetzung von "awkward" wäre.

Comment: *Überzwerch* war mir nicht bekannt, ist aber schön. Interessant auch, daß es wie *awkward* im übertragenen Sinne von Menschen gebraucht werden kann (Duden sagt "verschroben, mürrisch"). Darin ist es vielleicht mit *verquer* ("absonderlich, merkwürdig") vergleichbar.

Comment: Im Englischen heißt „awkward“ nur das Folgende (ein innerliches Gefühl): stell dir mal vor. Diene Ex-Frau hat das Sorgerecht für deine zwei Kinder aus der Ehe, aber sie hat wieder geheiratet. Jedes Wochenende, wenn du deine Kinder abholst, um die zu besuchen, glotzt der Mann deiner Ex-Frau dich an, weil er dich nicht mag. In dieser Situation, fühlst du dich „awkward“. Es ist ein peinlicher Moment? Nein. Auf keinen fall. Eine unangenehme Situation? Zwar, aber viel mehr. Vielleicht gibt es keine korrekte Übersetzung. Bitte, keine Anworten in englischer Sprache.

Comment: Da der SteveL in den Kommentaren unter seiner Frage klar gemacht hat, dass er/sie deutsch-sprachige Antworten bevorzugt, wäre es vielleicht sinnvoll, diese Antwort bilingual zu ergänzen.

Comment: Beim Schreiben war ich mir der Sprache gar nicht bewußt. Daher wohl auch die Tatsache, daß ich sogar eine Ergänzung auf Deutsch angefügt habe. Mixing my languages, that's a big no-no. Da die Leistung der Antwort im wesentlichen in den vergleichenden Übersetzungen besteht, würde ich aber von einer Übersetzung des Begleittextes absehen.